# Spinner not visible on fragment replacement

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I am using spinner in my android app, i am created spinner in xml and accessing with below code

```
Spinner filterSpinner; //Variable

if (filterSpinner==null)
    filterSpinner = (Spinner)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.core_voc_filter_spinner);
```

spinner is visible when it get initialised first time but when i am navigating to another fragment and coming back my spinner visibility is gone.

i am using filterSpinner variable to preserve in fragment replacement

Answer (score 1):

add this code to you oncreateView method inside fragment

```
if (rootView == null) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout_home, null);
        } else {
            ((ViewGroup) rootView.getParent()).removeView(rootView);
            return rootView;
        }
```

Comment: i am having spinner in fragmentA, i have selected some item in spinner and navigating to fragmentB. When i come back to fragmentA i need my spinner to show previously selected item